# SQL Count all matching rows unless they have a specific value in another column

Tags: sql, count

Here's the table that I am starting from

| ID | Group | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | Blue |
| 1 | b | Blue |
| 2 | a | red |
| 2 | b | red |
| 2 | e | N/A |
| 3 | a | green |
| 3 | b | green |
| 3 | c | green |
| 3 | e | N/A |

My goal is to count the number of times and ID number shows up in the table excluding entries that have a result of N/A.  Then I need those counts to show up in a additional column attached to each entry in the table.

| ID | Group | Result | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | Blue | 2 |
| 1 | b | Blue | 2 |
| 2 | a | red | 2 |
| 2 | b | red | 2 |
| 2 | e | N/A | 2 |
| 3 | a | green | 3 |
| 3 | b | green | 3 |
| 3 | c | green | 3 |
| 3 | e | N/A | 3 |

Here is what I am hoping to get to.  I have tried case functions and other forms of counting but keep getting syntax or aggregation errors.  So at the moment all I have is the select code for the table that is already forming.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Please edit the question and post the SQL (as text) that you are trying to make work.

Comment: Is 'N/A' stored as actual text, or does it indicate a null value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use sum window function over partition on id

```
select t1.*, sum(case when result <> 'N/A' then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by ID) as 'Count'  from table1 t1;
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `COUNT()` as an analytic function along with conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT ID, "Group", Result,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Result <> 'N/A' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) AS Count
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY ID;
```